# Python split tabspaced bilingual txt to two separate txt files (list) with newlines separating strings

Tags: python, unicode, split

I have a bi-lingual corpora (EN-JP) from tatoeba and want to split this into two separate files. The strings have to say on the same line respectively.

I need this for training an NMT in nmt-keras and training data has to be stored in separate files for each language. I tried several approaches, but since I'm an absolute beginner with python and coding in general I feel like I'm running in circles.

So far the best I managed was the following:

Source txt:

```
Go. 行け。
Go. 行きなさい。
Hi. やっほー。
Hi. こんにちは！
```

Code:

```
with open('jpns.txt', encoding="utf8") as f:
    columns = zip(*(l.split("\t") for l in f))

list1= list(columns)
print(list1)
```

```
[('Go.', 'Go.', 'Hi.', 'Hi.'), ('行け。\n', '行きなさい。\n', 'やっほー。\n', 'こんにちは！')]
```

Result with my code:

```
[('Go.', 'Go.', 'Hi.', 'Hi.'), ('行け。\n', '行きなさい。\n', 'やっほー。\n', 'こんにちは！')]
```

English and Japanese get properly separated (into a Tuple?) but I'm stuck at figuring out how to export only English and how to export only Japanese to an `output.en` and an `output.jp` respecitvely.

Expected result:

**output.en**

```
Go.
Go.
Hi.
Hi.
```

**output.jp**

```
行け。
行きなさい。
やっほー。
こんにちは！
```

Each outputted strings should contain an \n after the string.

Please keep in mind that I'm a total beginner with coding, so I'm not exactly sure what I did after "zip" as I just found this here on stackoverflow. I'd be really gratful for a fully commented suggestion.

Comment: It's a good idea to format text files as code as well. That way you preserve the formatting and see the line breaks as intended. Also, triple-backticks don't work on SO. Instead, you have to indent by four spaces. You can do this automatically by highlighting a block of code and pressing the `{}` toolbar button, or **Ctrl + K** on your keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to be aware of is that iterating over a file retains the newlines. That means that in your two columns, the first has no newlines, while the second has newlines already appended to each line (except possibly the last).

Writing the second column is therefore trivial if you've already unpacked the generator `columns`:

```
with open('output.jp', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(list1[-1])
```

But you still have to append newlines to the first column (and possibly others if you go full-on multilingual). One way would be to append newlines to all the columns but the last. Another would be to strip the columns from the last column and process all of them the same.

You can achieve the result you want with a small loop, and another call to `zip`:

```
langs = ('en', 'jp')
for index, (lang, data) in enumerate(zip(langs, columns)):
    with open('output.' + lang, 'w') as f:
        if index < len(langs) - 1:
            data = (line + '\n' for line in data)
        f.writelines(data)
```

This approach replaces the tuple `data` with a generator that appends newlines, unless we are at the last column.

There are a couple of ways to insert newlines between each line in the output files. The one I show uses a lazy generator to append to each line individually. This should save a little memory. If you don't care about memory savings, you can output the whole file as a single string:

```
joiner = '\n' if index < len(langs) - 1 else ''
f.write(joiner.join(data))
```

You can even write the loop yourself and `print` to the file:

```
for line in data:
    print(line, file=f, end='\n' if index < len(args) - 1 else '')
```

**Addendum**

Let's also look at the line `columns = zip(*(l.split("\t") for l in f))` in detail, since it is a very common Python idiom for transposing nested lists, and is the key to getting the result you want.

The generator expression `l.split("\t") for l in f` is pretty straightforward: it splits each line in the file around tabs, giving you two elements, one in English, and one in Japanese. Adding a `*` in front of the generator expands it so that each two-element row becomes a separate argument to `zip`. `zip` then re-combines the respective elements of each row, so you get a column of the English elements, and a column of the Japanese elements, effectively transposing your original "matrix".

The result is that `columns` is a generator over the columns. You can convert it to a `list`, but that is only necessary for viewing. The generator will work fine for the code shown above.

Comment: @blhsing. Thanks. I was sorry to see your answer go. If you don't mind, I will mention the technique you suggested.

Comment: No problem. Great minds think alike after all, and you do give much better explanations than I do. The last line is the only real difference in our codes, and mine was not entirely accurate because it would miss a trailing newline, although that can indeed be fixed by simply adding a trailing newline: `f.write('\n'.join(lines) + '\n')`.

Comment: This is pretty much perfect! Thanks so much for the quick replies and great explanation! The only thing I noticed is that the japanese output now has an extra space between each line, most likely because it already has an /n after every string. 

I guess I would have to strip that first... I tried adding .strip to data in f.writelines(line + "\n" for line in data), but since data is a tuple it does not have the strip attribute.

Comment: @Mad Physicist: Thanks I already managed, just couldn't edit the comment anymore:

I applied **.strip("\n")** to the first **line**  in `f.writelines(line + "\n" for line in data)` and it worked perfectly.

Also (on windows) I had to add **encoding='utf8'** in `with open('output.' + lang, 'w') as f:`; or japanese would have stayed empty.
ErrorMsg:_(return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: character maps to <undefined>)_